# python: group elements of a tuple having the same first element

Tags: python, list, tuples

i have a tuple like this

```
[
(379146591, 'it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1), 
(4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), 
(4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)
]
```

i would like to get instead this:

```
[
(379146591, (('it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1)), 
(4746004, (('it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), ('it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)))
]
```

so the for any element, anything that is not the first element is inside a sub-tuple of it, and if the following element has the same element as first element, it will be set as another sub-tuple of the previous one.

so i can do:

```
for i in data:
    # getting the first element of the list
    for sub_i in i[1]:
        # i access all the tuples inside
```

are there some functions to do this?

Comment: I think this would be a good use for a dictionary. You can use the first element as the key and the value can be a list of tuples.

Comment: @Kyle ok thank you  i was wondering if there was a library having a function like this or i have to write my own by me

Comment: You shouldn't need a library for this.  I can write a sample here with dictionaries. Check out the answer by @Psidom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's pretty simple with `defaultdict`; You initialize the default value to be a list and then append the item to the value of the same key:

```
lst = [
    (379146591, 'it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1), 
    (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), 
    (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)
]

from collections import defaultdict    ​
d = defaultdict(list)

for k, *v in lst:
    d[k].append(v)

list(d.items())
#[(4746004,
#  [('it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2),
#   ('it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)]),
# (379146591, [('it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1)])]
```

---

If order is important, use an `OrderedDict` which can remember the insertion orders:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
​
for k, *v in lst:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

list(d.items())
#[(379146591, [['it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1]]),
# (4746004,
#  [['it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2],
#   ['it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3]])]
```

Comment: You don't need OrderedDict starting with CPython 3.6 and all other Python implementations starting with Python 3.7 because regular `dict`s [maintain insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) (and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get the first item). The only thing is that your data needs to already be sorted so that the groups appear one after the other (if you've used the `uniq` and `sort` bash commands, same idea), you can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) for this

```
import operator
from itertools import groupby

data = [
    (379146591, "it", 55, 1, 1, "NON ENTRARE", "NonEntrate", 55, 1),
    (4746004, "it", 28, 2, 2, "NON ENTRARE", "NonEntrate", 26, 2),
    (4746004, "it", 28, 2, 2, "TheBestTroll Group", "TheBestTrollGroup", 2, 3),
]

data = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(0))  # this might be unnecessary
for k, g in groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print(k, list(g))
```

Will output

```
4746004 [(4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)]
379146591 [(379146591, 'it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1)]
```

In your case, you also need to remove the first element from your lists of values. Change the last two lines of the above to:

```
for k, g in groupby(data, operator.itemgetter(0)):
    print(k, [item[1:] for item in g])
```

Output:

```
4746004 [('it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), ('it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)]
379146591 [('it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Python3 variable unpacking and `OrderedDict` to retain order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
l = [
  (379146591, 'it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1), 
  (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), 
 (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)
]

for a, *b in l:
  if a in d:
     d[a].append(b)
  else:
     d[a] = [b]

final_data = [(a, tuple(map(tuple, b))) for a, b in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[(379146591, (('it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1),)), (4746004, (('it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), ('it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)))]
```

Comment: You don't need OrderedDict starting with CPython 3.6 and all other Python implementations starting with Python 3.7 because regular `dict`s [maintain insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html)

Answer (score 0):

u can use collection.defaultdict:

```
data = [
    (379146591, 'it', 55, 1, 1, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 55, 1), 
    (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'NON ENTRARE', 'NonEntrate', 26, 2), 
    (4746004, 'it', 28, 2, 2, 'TheBestTroll Group', 'TheBestTrollGroup', 2, 3)
    ]
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(list)
a = defaultdict(list)


from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(list)

for d in data:
    a[d[0]].append(d[1:])

for k,v in a.items():
    a[k] = tuple(a[k])

print(dict(a))
```